# Why won't it enter the while loop? Using fscanf to read in from a csv

Tags: c, file, struct, scanf

So I'm trying to read data in from a file and store it in a struct. I'm using `fscanf` for this, but for some reason it won't enter the while loop at all. It's reading in the file, closing it, and there are no memory leaks. Why could this be happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


typedef unsigned long size_t;


typedef struct {
    char wt_id[128];
    char postcode[128];
    int pop_served;
    char wt_manager[128];
    double x;
    double y;
} watchtower_t;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int num_records = 0;
    char *record = NULL;
    size_t record_len = 512;
    
    int current_size = 5;

    
    //watchtower_t **wt_array = NULL;
    watchtower_t temp;
    

    
    char *filename = NULL;
    filename = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(filename,"r");
    assert(file);

    
    if(argc<2){
        return 0;
  
    }

    while(fscanf(file, "%[^,],%[^,],%d,%[^,],%lf,%lf",temp.wt_id,temp.postcode,&temp.pop_served,temp.wt_manager,&temp.x,&temp.y)==6){
        printf("Enters the while loop");
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
    
}
```

sample line from the csv file:
WT3525YPKBW,3525,433,DeniseRoberts,143.32090727836928,-36.14524876420747

Comment: Can you show an example of a file you're trying to read? The code you provide does seem to successfully read a line for me.

Comment: so I'm running it on my terminal, with

./tower dataset_10.csv

(dataset_10.csv is the file)

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong terminal commands to run it?

Comment: The code as written assumes 2 or more command line arguments. Perhaps you meant `if(argc!=2)`.

Comment: @Lundin, I tried that, still the same error

Comment: Try `" %[^,], %[^,],%d , %[^,],%lf ,%lf"` with those spaces added. The `%[` specifier does not automatically filter whitespace, unlike `%d` and `%lf`.

Comment: @Weather Vane it's still doing the same thing

Comment: Please show two or three lines of the file as requested, formatted as code. If not 6, what value *does* `fscanf` return?

Comment: @NiVeR [`argv[0]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) is the name of the program, provided by the host environment.

Comment: Here are a few lines of the csv file:
WT3525YPKBW,3525,433,Denise Roberts,143.32090727836928,-36.14524876420747
WT3701KWYIQ,3701,269,Martha Moore,147.39302957919313,-36.254894160169314
WT3779NULEK,3779,197,Aida Kuhnle,146.11080887018696,-37.67951918079387
WT3530RJWDT,3530,63,Troy Clark,143.0834668479817,-35.79299394885817

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68926584/edit) the question, and format those lines as code, so they are *exactly* like the file.

Comment: *Side note:* your order of operations is out of whack: you check `argc` *after* assuming `argv[1]` to contain useful data. Also, `return 0; exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` makes no sense - `exit` will never be reached (calling from `main` has the same effect as `return` anyway), and those two return codes are the inverse of one another.

Comment: Okay I've edited the question and added a sample csv line

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem sorry. From the four lines in comment it outputs `Enters the while loopEnters the while loopEnters the while loopEnters the while loop`. You need a debugger to find out what is happening.