# Comma seperated input to be stored in multiple varibles using scanf in C

Tags: c, csv, scanf

I am trying to make a database program in which datas can be given through input. I am having issues while using scanf function to take inputs.

Sample Input:

> 101, Rohit Joshi, New York, Texas, 05:30 AM, 1200

User will enter this data in the input field and I want to store each value in separate variable.
What I have tried is here,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int sn,price;
    char name[20],place1[20],place2[20],time[20];

    scanf("%d, %19[^,]s, %19[^,]s, %19[^,]s, %19[^,]s, %d",&sn,name,place1,place2,time,&price);
    printf("sn=%d name=%s place1=%s place2=%s time=%s price=%d\n",sn,name,place1,place2,time,price);
}
```

But this is not working properly. The output given is

> sn=101 name=Rohit Joshi place1= place2 time= price=16

I have no idea how this output is being produced. What is the proper way of using scanf for this?  If scanf cannot be used for this purpose, what can be the way to do this?

Comment: Thank you, that was so simple but I didn't think of that before. That worked well !

Comment: @RohitJoshi "have no idea how this output is being produced." --> to get an idea, code should check the return value of `scanf()` and compare to 6.

Comment: Note that the format `%[]` is not a subset of the format `%s`. They are quite different, and behave differently too. Frequent Beginner Mistake.

Comment: You may want to use a `struct` to store your data similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68926584/why-wont-it-enter-the-while-loop-using-fscanf-to-read-in-from-a-csv